# Как заблокировать доступ к изображению?

Tags: html, .htaccess

```
body {
background: #FFFFFF url(Ссылка на картинку);
}
```

Чтоб при просмотре страницы картинка отображалась, а при переходе или скачивании было 403.

Comment: Никак. На стороне клиента точно никак. (на стороне сервера возможно)

Comment: Максимум что можно сделать для "защиты" - сделать наложения прозрачных или полупрозрачных изображений одно на другое - тогда при сохранении будут глюки, и то есть "print screen".

Comment: Ну а на стороне сервера как это реализовать ?

Comment: Если картинка отображается у пользователя, то он может достать её из кеша бразуера, или просто из свойств страницы.

Comment: @VladD Почему не работает у меня данный код .`<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$">
order deny,allow
deny from all
</FilesMatch> ` При переходе по адресу mysite/img.jpg должно быть 403 но ее нет ?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы что-то выложили в интернет, то это можно скачать. Без исключений.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать в `.htaccess` вашего сайта:

Чтобы запретить другим сайтам пользоваться вашим трафиком и/или просто указывать прямые ссылки на ваши файлы (картинки), то добавьте в ваш `.htaccess` файл следующие строки:

```
# Запретить другим сайтам использовать прямые ссылки на ваши картинки
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
# Дальше список разрешенных доменов
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?sitename.ru.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?sitename.ru:80.*$ [NC]
# IP сайта (домена)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://111.111.111.111.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://111.111.111.111:80.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?yandex.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?google. [NC]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?домен_дружественного сайта.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search?q=cache [NC]
# Форматы файлов, для которых устанавливается защита
# Выводит ошибку 403
# RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|bmp|gif|png|css|mov|swf|dcr|exe|rar|avi|vob|zip|pdf|txt|doc|flv|mp3|mp4)$ — [NC,F,L]
# или показывает спецрисунок вместо указанного
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|bmp|gif|png)$ files/images/nohotlink.jpg [NC,L]
```

В итоге все остальные сайты получат ошибку 403 Forbidden (т.е. Доступ запрещен) и ваша пропускная способность больше `не работает на других`.

Comment: А как же в браузере (Firefox) "информация о странице" - "мультимедиа" - "сохранить"? Не знаю как новый ie, старый вообще картинки в Temporary internet files хранил.

Comment: Я понял, ответ - запретить **другим сайтам**. В вопросе не указано запрещать клиенту, или другим сайтам.

Comment: @nick_n_a 8  что значит  `"информация о странице" - "мультимедиа" - "сохранить"?` ????

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan для RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|bmp|gif|png|css|mov|swf|dcr|exe|rar|avi|vob|zip|pdf|txt|doc|flv|mp3|mp4)$ — [NC,F,L] я должен указать RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ???